# Scribus will not let me set PDF Field to certain fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, scribus

I am using Scribus to design some PDF forms. The paper form the digital form is based from has individual boxes for letter inputs, therefore I want to use fixed width font, like *Courier New* with a fixed number of inputs to meet the boxes like if the form was being filled out on paper.

I can create a text frame and use any system font, but when I create a PDF text input, the font choices are only a subset of the available system fonts. I can use much more ornate fonts and they show up correctly when I render to PDF (PDF 1.4+). Is there a reason Scribus does not permit me to use the fonts I want in a PDF form input?

---

Here is a screenshot showing that for the PDF element, *Courier New* is not an option
[image]

However, I am able to successfully create a PDF where the font is set to *Bauhaus 93*:
[image]

---

Edit

Followed @JLuc's solution. Here was the before screenshot:
[image]

I have to do some more testing, but after unchecking the subset option it does seem I can select the font in the properties now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the *Files* menu for the *Document setup* entry that opens a setup dialog : go to the *Fonts* tab.
There, all fonts are listed and for each you can check or uncheck some property. 
It could be that the fonts you wish to use are not declared as to be embeded and scribus can not use them for input fields. 
Ensure that the *subset* checkbox is not checked for them. When the subset checkbox is not checked, the fonts are not embeded but vectorized.!

[image: screenshot of the Fonts preference tab]